# Java/Android - Doesn't add the two values of RatingBar?

Tags: java, android

Suppose I set the first value of ratingbar to 1 and also second value to 1,it doesn't add up to 2.Instead shows 1.01.0 .What's wrong here?

```
    RatingBar r1,r2;
    Button submit;
    r1 = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
    r2 = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar2);

     submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, String.valueOf(r1.getRating())+String.valueOf(r2.getRating()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //shows 1.01.0
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are using `+` with String objects and with int. The + operator for String has the meaning of concatenation. What do you want is achievable summing the values and then converting it to String. Change from

```
String.valueOf(r1.getRating())+String.valueOf(r2.getRating())
```

to

```
String.valueOf(r1.getRating() + r2.getRating())
```

Comment: Thanks...it helped :)